# Why is [CByte] not allowed as an Enum member when similar keywords can be used?

Tags: vba, enums, compiler-errors, special-characters

I have made the following (ill-advised) Enum:

```
Public Enum gtUnaryOperator
    [CBool]
    [CByte]
    [CCur]
    [CDate]
    [CDbl]
    [CDec]
    [CInt]
    [CLng]
    [CLngPtr]
    [CSng]
    [CStr]
    [CVar]
    [CVDate]
    [CVErr]
End Enum
```

... featuring the names of all the type conversion functions escaped in `[]` square brackets. This compiles fine, and I can refer to these enum members in code (provided I escape them - e.g. `?[CCur]` will print `2` in the immediate window)

However I can't use `[CByte]` in the same way - all the others work, but entering `?[CByte]` in the immediate window gives

> Compile Error, Expected "("

I've been trying to read through the language specification [3.3.5.3 Special Identifier Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/74e5bf34-2a30-420c-9d3b-9341fa4c4c09?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for answers, but it's a bit dense (or maybe I am) and anyway nothing leaps out as an explanation.

NB. fully qualifying:

```
gtUnaryOperator.[CByte]
```

... works fine, but I don't see why that should be necessary

---

Any reason CByte should be different from the others - I'm aware it's not just a normal function, but treated as a language keyword (unlike VBA.CByte), but so are all the rest of the type conversion functions (try changing your text colours).

[image]So I'm really at a loss!